# PingID 2 MFA automation with 32 Digit pairing key

Tags: key, pairing

in my project ping id is used for 2MFA and I was using 32 digit authentication to autoamate it. In current version somehow they have removed it or I cannot find it. Is there anyone who has knowladge about how to find it or any other way to automate 2 MFA? I was getting 32 digit key and by the help of TOTP generator I was creating 6 digit code then use it for authentication. Since couple of weeks I cannot produce the 32 digit key for new user. Old users' keys are still working which means there has to be a way to find it.

Many thanks for your help in advance

No way found because old version is not up anymore